# Ubuntu 19.10 freezes when performing high disk usage tasks

Tags: freeze

I have Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my laptop as a dual boot with Windows 10. I find that when I perform certain tasks that use the disk, Ubuntu will freeze up and I need to do hard shutdown.

I've noticed this most often when transferring files. For example, today I've tried twice to transfer about 20GB of data to a USB stick. While the files are transferring, the UI freezes up for a few seconds sometimes. But if I do something else at the same time, like watch a video, the system gets frozen completely.

If it freezes when watching a video, the entire UI and video will freeze, but the audio will continue. The longer the audio starts to play, it starts to stutter. After a few minutes, the audio gets stuck in an infinite loop, as if it's a record that's stuck.

The System Monitor shows a consistent ~2GB of memory usage (~50%) and ~150MB or swap usage (~7%). The CPU also stays within 10-20% usage. This stays stable the entire way through the file transfers, including before and during the freeze ups.

I don't have this issue when using Windows 10 to perform the same tasks. I assume this is because Windows does something to allocate resources differently or reserves a certain amount of system resources for the OS only, to prevent freezing.

Is there a setting or system file that can be tweaked to stop the system from freezing?

Ubuntu is very unstable because of this and it makes it very frustrating to do anything that involves high disk usage (most commonly transferring files, but I've had the same issues when running a program that creates a large file).

SYSTEM SPECS:

```
RAM: 4GB
CPU: Intel Core i5-5200U
HDD: 500GB (~200GB free) (Excluding Windows partition)
GRAPHICS: Intel® HD Graphics 5500
```

PARTITIONS:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVX-7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      525MB   567MB   41.9MB  fat32        Basic data partition          hidden
 3      567MB   701MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      701MB   1488MB  786MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 5      1488MB  333GB   331GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 8      333GB   490GB   157GB   ext4
 6      490GB   491GB   955MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag
 7      491GB   500GB   8997MB  ntfs         Microsoft recovery partition  hidden, diag
```

Ubuntu is installed on partition 8. The others are for my laptop manufacturer's recovery and of course there's Windows 10 on there as well. The Ubuntu partition primarily holds just the OS because I put most of my files on the Windows 10 partition so I can access them from both systems. However, the data I'm trying to copy is on the Ubuntu partition, not the Windows one.

FREE & VMSTAT OUTPUTS:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       1.5Gi       182Mi       189Mi       2.1Gi       1.8Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       142Mi       1.9Gi
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 6  3 145560 186356 536148 1651000    1   65   213   249  509   61 10  4 70 17  0
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "OK to freeze" setting (who would want that?) Check `top` and `free` before and during a freeze, if possible. Note the exact time of a freeze and review /var/log/syslog for that time.

Comment: Please open a terminal window and at the shell prompt, run `free -mh && vmstat && sudo parted -l` . Highlight and copy  the result. Then, come back here and click [edit] then paste the result into your question. Highlight it then click on the {} icon. That way, we can see your filesystem layout and swap space use. More info at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: @user535733 I completely forgot to mention it in my question, but I have watched System Monitor during the transfer because I originally thought my system was just running out of RAM. Memory usage stays at ~2GB (of 3.8GB) the entire time and the swap stays at ~150MB (of 2GB). CPU sits under 20% for the entire transfer. Neither the memory or the CPU spikes or even changes before or during the freezes.

Comment: @K7AAY I've added the information that you are looking for in the original question. The values were captured during a transfer that was causing intermittent freezing.